# Python regular expression A followed by B followed by C

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am new to *regular expressions*, I couldn't come up with a regex which can accept strings which are of the following form:

`A` followed by `B` followed by `C`.

Examples:

```
ABC, AAAC, CCC, AABBCCCC   are accepted

CCBBAAA, BCA, ABCABC       are rejected
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you mean OR condition: `A followed by B` OR `A followed by C`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by making all characters `zero or many` by using `*` quantifier and at the same time checking that either of them are present by using `lookahead`

**Regex:** `(?=[ABC])^A*B*C*$`

**Explanation:**

`(?=[ABC])` Lookahead for presence of either characeters to avoid blank string from being matched.

`^A*B*C*$` Matches `zero` or `many` `A` followed by `B` followed by `C`.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FkjLQG/2/)**

---

**Update:**

As pointed out by Sebastian Proske `^(?=[ABC])A*B*C*$` takes less no of steps thus increasing performance.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FkjLQG/4/)**

Comment: I'd move the lookahead inside the anchors, so that the `^` is checked first.

Comment: @SebastianProske: How is that different from current one ? Any cases of false matches ?

Comment: @SebastianProske: You are right. My regex is taking more steps than what you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: @UditSareen: It's encouraged to Up Vote answers which are helpful and mark as Solved if it really solved your problem. Welcome to StackOverflow. ☺☻

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet

```
import re
inputStr = "AABBCC"
inputStr2 = "BBCCAA"
regex = r"(^A*B*C*$)"
matchObj = (len(inputStr) and re.match(regex, inputStr)) or None;
print(matchObj);
```